# viewChangeListeners not working in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-model

So basically, I want a directive that updates the class of an input whenever the viewValue isn't empty. Here is the code.

```
    angular.module('app').directive('input', function() { return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        if (ngModelController === null) return;
        var updateClass = function() {
          if (!(ngModelController.$isEmpty(ngModelController.$viewValue))) {
            element.addClass('input-has-value');
          } else {
            element.removeClass('input-has-value');
          }
        }
        ngModelController.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
          updateClass();
        });
    }
    };
    });
```

But I'm missing something since it never fires the updateClass method. What am I doing wrong? It never fires the updateClass method..

Comment: Create reproducible example in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/). Also you are applying the same class `input-has-value` regardless of the input value is empty or not

Comment: Did you solve this?  My $viewChangeListeners function isn't being called either.